# Remove div class on page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div

```
<div id="commonConsultationPopup" class="overlayPopup"></div>
```

I want to remove class on page loading.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
});
```

But its not working.

Comment: Is jQuery lib loaded ?

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: There is no error on browser console.

Comment: If jQuery is loaded, and there are no errors the next step is to try: `console.log($("#commonConsultationPopup").length)` and if that logs `1` (as it should, if the element exists on the page on document ready), try `console.log($("#commonConsultationPopup.overlayPopup").length)` to see if the given element really has that specific class.

Comment: @Abhay Are you in wordpress ?

Comment: @Firefog     No not in wordpress.

Comment: @Abhay I have added a demo that your code work 100% you can load jQuery library correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass();
});
```

But it will remove all the classes from the the given `div`.

Comment: Thanks buddy it's working and removing all classes is OK in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this function does what you think that it does.  From the manual:

> removeclass(className)
>
> Type: String
>
> One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute >of each matched element.

Please notice that the manual says that it will remove the class *from the class attribute*. It does *not* state that it will remove the entire element.

If you wish to remove the entire div, you want the `.remove()` function. To use this, use a finder to locate the div (possibly by class name?) and then call `remove()` on it.

Comment: I believe that **is** what the OP wants. From his question: "*I want to remove class on page loading.*" It looks like he only wants to remove the class on the div, but not the entire div itself.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Let's see what he says.

Comment: Yes i just want to remove my class.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a class on document ready use this JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
});
```

To remove a class from a element on window load use this instead:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
});
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Remove class example</title>
  <!-- We are using jQuery 3.1.0 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- You can also use jQuery 12.1.4 like this -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="overlayPopup" id="commonConsultationPopup"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Use this if you want to wait for the page to be ready:
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
    });
    // Use this instead if you want to wait for the page to load:
    // jQuery(window).load(function() {
    //   $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
    // });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck and all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="commonConsultationPopup" class="overlayPopup"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And result

[image]

Don't view source. View content by Firebug or something similar.

Comment: I'm viewing it via firebug.

Answer (score 0):

The Code 100% work See a Demo here if its not work the color should red . but it not that mean the class removed. You can also inspect you code to see the code by pressing F12.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#commonConsultationPopup').removeClass('overlayPopup');
});
```

```css
.overlayPopup{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="commonConsultationPopup" class="overlayPopup"> The class removed </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS seems perfect, just check two things

1. jQuery is loaded.
2. replace "$" with "jQuery" Specially when you are working in WordPress.

HTML

```
<div id="commonConsultationPopup" class="overlayPopup">test</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#commonConsultationPopup").removeClass("overlayPopup");
});
```

[Check This Working CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sabirHussain/pen/OXzGvy)